# Horizontal and vertical alignment of div

Tags: jquery, html, vertical-alignment, tablelayout

I am using JQuery. I have a div that contains a table. I have 4 rows in the table each with one col. Each row contains a line or two of text

I want to make each row with height = 100 px and have the text centered horizontally and vertically.

Can this be done?

Comment: Hard to help with no code / sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the text in each table cell aligned vertically and horizontally, you can use CSS.

```
table td {
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[See it working here.](http://jsbin.com/icohu4/edit)

Comment: wont this make every td in the page have these properties?

Comment: Take that back. I'm going to mark yours as the answer. You answered the question. Problem is I didn't ask the right questions. Thanks!

Comment: @alex - the solution you provided only works for text. for some reason when I place a label in it does not work. Started new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960510/horizonal-and-vertical-alignment-of-label-in-div-in-table-row

Comment: @kralco626 I answered your new question.

Answer (score 0):

very simple:

```
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle:
```