# horizontal and vertical alignment of label in div in table row

Tags: jquery, html, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have code:

```
<tr>
    <td align="center" style="height: 50px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"   >
           <div class="hoverClass ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;width:100%;height:100%">
                 <label style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle" >Streetlight Repair</label>
           </div>
     </td>
</tr>
```

I want it to be a cell with a div containing a label. 
I want the div to take up the whole cell. and the label to be centered within the div. However the label sits at the top left of the div.

Comment: shift your style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle" to div

Comment: I have that on the style of div. If you scroll right.

Answer (score 3):

If the height is definitely 50px, set the line-height CSS of the label to 50px;

To get the label in the middle horizontally, set margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto;

Comment: So this is a whole table of these. So some of the labels wrap and take up two lines.

Comment: The auto horizontal margin will work only if you define an explicit width I'm pretty sure.

Comment: i could define an explication width for the label. It is in a cell with a defined width. I'll try that. But i still have an issue with the vertical alignment.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one line, you can not use the `line-height` property to hack middle alignment.

Easiest way is to play with top and bottom padding.

Comment: ugh. So basically if I wanted to make the content decided at runtime vis JavaScript i'm screwed... Unless I made JavaScript decide if the text would be wrapped and how many lines it would need and then set the padding accordingly...?

Comment: @kralco626 Yes, or try playing with `padding`. You can also use the middle align hack, but it is ugly with IE (wrap with 2 divs). Refer to article linked in blog :)